# How to show file on harddrive asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, show

I have a web page in my asp.net mvc website where user uploads the file. Now my problem is, i need to show the link in a page on click of which user will be able to view the file.

User can upload file or types doc,docx and pdf.

How can i do this.

Please help,

Thank's

Comment: be cartful when a user upload an aspx file :)

Answer (score 1):

The most simple thing you can do is to use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(..)`, like this:

```
var myModel = new myModel {
    Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp")
}
```

However, `Directory.GetFiles(..)` will give you an array of strings, which may a bit hard to work with. If you need to use the files in a bit more object oriented manner, refer to the `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` classes.

Example:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
foreach (FileInfo fi in directory.GetFiles()) {
   Console.WriteLine(@"FileName: {0}", fi.Name);
}
```

MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for the reply.

But i have been looking for something like this, which solved my problem.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        string extension = id.Substring(id.IndexOf(".") + 1);
        string contentType = string.Empty;

        if (extension == "doc" || extension == "docx")
        {
            contentType = "application/msword";
        }
        else if (extension == "pdf")
        {
            contentType = "application/pdf";
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid file");
        }
        return File(Server.MapPath("~/Docs/" + id), contentType);
    }
```

Where id parameter in above code is the filename.

Thank's

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking how to avoid your download links from being intercepted by MVC routing have a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2010/11/11/mvc-s-ignoreroute-syntax.aspx